# Lubuntu 14.04.1, new installation. Error: "unable to mount /boot"

Tags: boot, mount, lubuntu, lxpanel, aptdaemon

This is a nearly new install of Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and I'm getting an error at beginning of every boot, beginning about the 6th boot after install. The PC is a 2004 HP ze4200 laptop: 1.8 ghz Celeron M with 1 gb RAM and 80 gb drive. Was running fine on WinXP SP3 and I cleaned the drive off to test Lubuntu 14 LTS. No anti-virus is installed yet.

The error: as the PC gets going, several lines of code reffing items not loading and/or mounting go by... too fast to read most of it.

Next, the beginning boot screen shows and the Lubuntu graphic with 5 load dots appears. The dots change color sequentually as expected. Quickly, an error appears under this. Most of it says: "error unable to mount /boot". I'm given the options of "S" to skip or "M" manual recovery. The "M" isn't helpful... I don't know Linux commands like I do DOS. So I click "S". The password screen appears and I enter it. Desktop loads. All seems fine... almost.

{The following may be separate problem}

Next, irregularly, as destop loads, I MAY get 2 internal error notices which overlap each other. For each had to use my password to get to show info and report windows... (password needed for everything... I'm really getting tired of that!!!) When they do appear, I select details. The list of info is long and will not let me select any of it for a "right click > copy". So, the general reasons are below:

1) "lxpanel 0.6.1-0ubuntu3" has crashed

2) "aptdaemon 1.1.1-lubuntu5" has crashed

Also, as I type this error report, sometimes cursor jumps to unexpected locations on Leafpad. And Firefox too I just noticed (but not as much). (Note: I have manually disabled the touchpad to stop "palm dragging" and no inputs are being accepted by it.)

I have not yet found equivolent of WinXP "Device Manager" to tell me what hardware didn't load correctly.

Finally, I have done recommended updates online the day after install (today). The problems occurred before and after. So, what's going on and how do I get past these errors?

Comment: Solution: reinstall WinXP and sell laptop. Find another PC to test any Linux distro. Sigh...